# Migrating polyline sidewalk data into centerline (two lines into one without attribute loss) using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I'm in the process of amalgamating several sidewalk datasets which require updating. All data I intend to consolidate within my centerline is based off of older versions of the data, and is a single line. I got my hands on some external data that tracked a portion of my city's sidewalk infrastructure. I am hoping to pull some of the attributes from it and into my city wide dataset.

While the sidewalk data represents the same roads as the centerline, it is a series of segments set on either side of the centerline. The end points also don't align with any similarity to the intersection nodes/segment end points of the centerline itself (Ex: centerline can have 4 segments along a road whereas there are 10 segments of the sidewalks).

[image: Sidewalk data]

[image: Centerline data]

I created a buffered polygon of the centerline and then attempted a spatial join but found that in doing so, many segments from the sidewalk data get removed in favor of a single one, relative to the centerline segment itself it was nearest to.

Secondly, the sidewalk data segments carry their own unique attributes (So not dual lines with one attribute table row) which I am hoping to migrate over. If I can join the data successfully, I'm not sure how to accommodate data from two lines being accurately represented within the centerline.

Should I completely forgo the single line data and start from scratch with a dual line set?

We have some topological networks and other dual line type options...none of which relate to the centerline in any way.

Comment: Not sure on your licensing for ArcGIS Advanced but see Collapse Dual Lines To Centerline https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/collapse-dual-lines-to-centerline.htm

Comment: Would there be any risk of existing attribute loss using this tool? The crux for me is to retain the existing attributes as they currently are. In my mind I'm hoping to facilitate a segment to segment transition. What escapes me is how to account for the potential of several sidewalk segments with discreet attributes potentially being merged into a single centerline segment.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is some mix between the operation of Merge Divided Roads tool and Simplify Line tool, you may look at the geralization toolset concept as well (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/merge-divided-roads.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Esmaeel. Could I trouble you to expand on what you envision being feasible using those tools?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMedyna. I thought of it as a small chunk to aid achieving spatial match to join the data normally, but looking again at your attributes and the segments differences you mentioned I think I rushed into storming idea, my bad. I can't really see obvious way to address the differences in these segments from a screenshot and it doesn't seem easy to guarantee no data loss but I hope the following suggestions would help you solve some chunks of your problem this time.

Comment: @ChrisMedyna For segment to segment transition you may look at Split Line By Match tool. There is also Transfer Attribute tool which is designed for similar aim (update old data), this shall transfer the attributes considering the segments differences. Finally. following up on Collapse Dual Lines To Centerline tool as suggested by Mapperz, you may compare the results from transfer attribute and from joining with the LeftLn_FID and RightLn_FID fields resulted from collapse to centerline and see how each behave corresponding to your data. hope this would help in making a step ahead this time!

Comment: @Esmaeel Thanks so much for providing me more context. I shall give these a try and report back. Really appreciate you taking the time to assist!